# Flow inject "arbitrary" properties type annotation ('inject' from mobx-react)

Tags: reactjs, templates, flowtype

I am using flow types with `mobx-react` as provider for stores.  mobx-react provides the store dat using a utility function that creates HOCs:

`inject('a', 'b' ....)` returns a function That takes a react component and returns a component with properties 'a' and 'b' set.

ie:

```
type PropTy = {
    eventStore: EventStore; //or well somewhere else set
}

inject('eventStore')(class EventView extends React.Component<PropTy>) {
    render() {
        return <div>this.props.eventStore.length</div>
    }
}
```

I understand that this cannot be 100% safe: there is no way to know for sure the type "injected" (via a string) is the actual type. But for now I wish to ignore that part. I wish to focus on using said components. -- Where I use this component flow "complains" that I haven't set all required properties. (Due to me not setting `eventStore` explicitly.

So for the type I tried the following:

```
inject: <Config: {}>(...args: Array<string>) =>
    ((React.AbstractComponent<Config>) =>
        React.AbstractComponent<$Diff<Config, args>>
    ),
```

However this complains with flow `cannot resolve args` at the inner function. - How would I annotate this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with:

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare function inject<Config: {}, InjectedConfig: {}>(
  ...args: Array<$Keys<InjectedConfig>>
): (React.AbstractComponent<Config> => React.AbstractComponent<$Diff<Config, InjectedConfig>>);

type FooProps = { a: number, b: string };
function Foo({ a, b }: FooProps) {
  return a + b;
}

type InjectedProps = { a: number };
const injectA = inject<FooProps, InjectedProps>('a');
const injectB = inject<FooProps, InjectedProps>('b'); // error

const Bar = injectA(Foo);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Foo a={1} b="hi" />
      <Bar b="bye" />
      <Bar b={1} /> // error
    </>
  );
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdAJlrgDbKVwECuAdvsAi84wXgCsWMADwBhIQWABzAFxwA3gF8ANHACS4yVkZzeCleo0A+ABR04cAHROOi1KoCCUKMgCeUgCQA0lg+qFL6EvhGJmaWlnQAlKrW2HgwDu4ARqgw3vhy4EJYvNIxSpZwALwVqfgZ2blpBZC8xdL+ACLABASy8ko6EYbG-YpxCfR0MD5gWHAAYhAQAArEYOiV6iiqvNwgmVhQOpmqOVCiinAa9Dz8MILCixDWaijHV6pPqxDrCep2cEoMG4UGEyDgAGo4Jl6BoGNNZnoDFFGN91lUtsgdnsDlArvRcEIciJkTB3BjRJFpF81qhBqSjGjUDYyMgyBM6ITeMTKZIAEIU0lSGk-OlIqmM2kszLsmhwAD08rgh2IUAYXOJfI4gqp7msTw5dFuAiEcHcYDA1j+agBQJBwls9nsUniTqdwqWKEqagAjBpoZUAEQAC2AgYVrrdcCkWrxmSDmR8WHD8sjbpj2vjvv9qYBztz9g5cLoQA)

I noticed that if you do not pass in `InjectedProps` to `inject`, Flow will not always infer the right thing. So I would recommend always declaring what `InjectedProps` is to ensure that Flow correctly validates `args` and the JSX parameters.

[Try Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdAJlrgDbKVwECuAdvsAi84wXgCsWMADwBhIQWABzAFxwA3gF8ANHACS4yVkZzeCleo0A+ABR04cAHROOi1KoCCUKMgCeUgCQA0lg+qFL6EvhGJmaWlnQAlKrW2HgwDu4ARqgw3vhy4EJYvNIxSpZwALwVqfgZ2blpBZC8xdL+ACLABASy8ko6EYbG-YpxCfR0MD5gWHAAYhAQAArEYOiV6iiqvNwgmVhQOpmqOVCiinAa9Dz8MILCixDWaijHV6pPqxDrCep2cEoMG4UGEyDgAGo4Jl6BoGLghDkRAZ8O4qsjIjBrGRkGQJnQEbwkaJMQAhdEkyTYzJ4mhwAD09Lgh2IUHhiPgpI4FJRMHc1ie+LotwEQjg7jAYGsfzUAKBIOEtns9ik8WVyqkTxQlTUAEYNNDKgAiAAWwCNDLV6rgUi5UENRsyPiwFvpVvVtu5mR1+stAJVboB+LhdCAA) without `InjectedProps`.